# ASP.Net & EF Core 2 and Concurrency token error

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0

Entity Framework Core 2, added a concurrency token property to model

```
[Timestamp]
public byte[] Timestamp { get; set; }
```

Controller Edit fails

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(Guid id, [Bind("Id,Name,Description,IsDeleted,ParentId")] ItemStatus itemStatus)
        {
            if (id != itemStatus.Id)
                return NotFound();

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    _context.Update(itemStatus);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
                catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
                {
                    if (!ItemStatusExists(itemStatus.Id))
                    {
                        return NotFound();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }

            ViewData["ParentId"] = new SelectList(_context.ItemStatus, "Id", "Description", itemStatus.ParentId);
            return View(itemStatus);
        }
```

the specific error I am receiving occurs when SaveChangesAsync occurs.  catch pops and when I step in it goes straight to the throw.

> DbUpdateConcurrencyException: Database operation expected to affect 1
>   row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s). Data may have been modified or
>   deleted since entities were loaded. See
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=527962 for information on
>   understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.
>
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.AffectedCountModificationCommandBatch.ThrowAggregateUpdateConcurrencyException(int
>   commandIndex, int expectedRowsAffected, int rowsAffected)

searching for the error message doesn't help.  did find this article but it appears to be no help.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/concurrency

Comment: You are not including (binding) the `Timestamp` property of the passed in `ItemStatus` object, what do you expect to happen?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/concurrency  this is what I followed.  it doesn't say anything about 'binding'.  what did I miss?

Comment: Because the topic is about EF Core. While your method is part of ASP Core controller or something. So, the EF Core concurrency tokens assume that you have read the original data in your object, then you modified some properties, then trying to save - the token will be used to ensure the data is not modified by another user after you have read it. Since your controller seem to not populate the timestamp property, it will be null, hence the concurrency check will fail.

Comment: Ivan StoeV I edited title to and tags to include asp.net core

Comment: fix the timestamp populating incorrectly?

Comment: All I can say is that you must ensure the `Timestamp` being field read must flow between your controller get, view(s), and controller edit actions. You probably need some hidden field in the view or something. But I'm afraid ASP Core is out of my experience (I can help only with EF Core related stuff), may be someone else can assist you with that part. Good luck.

Comment: For the ASP.NET Core specific stuff, can you show your View that ends up posting to this `Edit` action?

Comment: I need to add a hidden input in my edit/delete view. missed that section and its found here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/concurrency

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as indicated in the comments, I was missing a hidden field to 'save' the timestamp in the view.

Followed this example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/concurrency

for clarity added my altered Edit.  I had to do something similar to Delete too.  this needs to be added to the Edit view `<input type="hidden" asp-for="Timestamp" />`

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(Guid id, [Bind("Id,Name,Description,ParentId,Timestamp")] ItemStatus itemStatus)
        {
            if (id != itemStatus.Id)
                return NotFound();

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    _context.Update(itemStatus);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
                catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
                {
                    if (!ItemStatusExists(itemStatus.Id))
                    {
                        return NotFound();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }

            ViewData["ParentId"] = new SelectList(_context.ItemStatus, "Id", "Description", itemStatus.ParentId);
            return View(itemStatus);
        }
```